# How to show Google Calendar events in the Clock widget?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, calendar, google-calendar, akonadi

I've just added Google Calendar account in Korganizer and it works fine, but these events don't show up in the Clock widget. Is it possible?

Note: this question is about KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old thread I know but still...

Once you have added the google account to korganizer and have it all sync'd up you should be able to see your calendars. You then need to do as Nik Reiman said and right click on clock ->Digital clock settings ->Calendar ->Add check to "Show events".

I then found that to actually see the results come up I had to skip back a month and then forward, it then refreshed the events in the widget.

Answer (score 1):

There are some known bugs with Korganizer not displaying recurring calendar events from GCal. There are several workarounds which usually involve running shell scripts with cron in order to sync Google calendars locally.

Comment: It's not showing anything at all. Do you have it displaying any event?

Comment: Yeah, for me it at least displays all events, it's just that recurring ones don't show up in the menu bar.

Comment: in the Clock widget?

Comment: Yeah, exactly ping @int_ua

Comment: Turns out I was using some old method to add the Google account. I've deleted it and re-set new one. Now it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Nice! BTW do recurring events work properly now?

Comment: Haven't checked recurring ones but the timezone looks ignored :(

Comment: @int_ua : can you explain your solutions, or post a link to it?

Comment: they doesn't work anymore ;(

Comment: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=215&t=117985

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
->right click on clock
->Digital clock settings
->Calendar
->Add check to "Show events"